# Creating an instance of Num class

Tags: haskell

I am relatively new to learning haskell.

I have the following abstract data type

```
data Scalar = 
    Scalar Integer
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I want to be able to do the following operation on the Scaler type:

```
> (Scalar 10) + 1
> Scalar 11
```

To do this I tried making the `Scalar` an instance of the `num` class like this:

```
instance Num Scalar where
  (Scalar i1) + i2 = (Scalar (i1+i2))
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? And whats the correct way to do this?

**Edit:**
The error I am getting is:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `Scalar '
> In the second argument of `(+)', namely `i2'
> In the first argument of `Scalar ', namely `(i1 + i2)'
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, because the type of `+` is:

```
λ> :t (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

So, it operates on the type of same data. In your case you are trying to add a type of `Scalar` and `Integer` which isn't valid. You can define an instance like this:

```
instance Num Scalar where
    (Scalar i1) + (Scalar i2) = Scalar (i1 + i2)
```

And it will operate on `Scalar` type:

```
λ> Scalar 3 + Scalar 4
Scalar 7
```

But if you really want to do this, you can create your own special function for that:

```
addNumtoScalar :: Integer -> Scalar -> Scalar
addNumtoScalar x (Scalar y)  = Scalar (x + y)
```

And then you can add using this function,

```
λ> addNumtoScalar 3 (Scalar 7)
Scalar 10
```

Or in an infix fashion:

```
λ> 3 `addNumtoScalar` (Scalar 7)
Scalar 10
```

As @user5402 has commented, you can define the `fromInteger` function of `Num` typeclass and then use that in your addition. Something like this:

```
instance Num Scalar where
    (Scalar x) + (Scalar y) = Scalar (x + y)
    fromInteger x = Scalar x
```

Now, you can use integer literals and they will be automatically converted to `Scalar` values when necessary, e.g.:

```
λ> 3 + Scalar 7
Scalar 10
```

Comment: Hmm, I now understand why it isn't possible. But building up from your `addNumtoScalar` function. Is it possible to name the function (`+`) without conflicting with prelude?

Comment: @Krimson I don't think so, because you have to anyway use the `+` funcion inside the definition of `addNumtoScalar`. But even if it was possible, I would recommend you not to do that for readability purpose. If you want to really use a operator, just create a different plus operator for your Scalar type.

Comment: Instead of a specialized `addNumToScalar` function, the Haskell way is to define the `fromInteger` function for `Scalar` - i.e. `fromInteger n = Scalar n`. Then you can use integer literals like 1, 5, 47 and have them converted automatically to `Scalar 1`, `Scalar 5`, `Scalar 47` when performing arithmetic on `Scalar` types.

Comment: @user5402 Yeah, that would be even more elegant. Updated that to include in the answer.

Comment: @user5402 That is even better. Thanks

Comment: I made a small edit to the answer to demonstrate how you don't even have to use `fromInteger` for literals.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a `Scalar` and an `Integer` (e.g. `Scalar 10 + 1`); you should wrap the second value in a Scalar before adding. Thus, your instance should look like this:

```
instance Num Scalar where
  (Scalar i1) + (Scalar i2) = (Scalar (i1+i2))
```

However, the `Num` typeclass provides requires several other methods besides `+` be implemented. Instead of writing all that manually, you can use the GHC GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving extension to handle all that for you:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Scalar = Scalar Integer deriving (Eq,Show,Num)
```

This will automatically derive the `Num` instance for `Scalar` based on how `Integer` implements the `Num` typeclass. This approach requires you to use a newtype, but it sounds like that's appropriate for your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's something wrong with your definition:

```
(Scalar i1) + i2 = (Scalar (i1+i2))
```

That should be the following:

```
(Scalar i1) + (Scalar i2) = Scalar (i1+i2)
```

Secondly, if you look at the [documentation of the `Num` typeclass](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num)

You will see the part about the minimal complete definition.

```
(+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-))
```

You've implemented `(+)`, but none of the others.

Lastsly, if you post a problem, include the error that you're getting please.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out the types on both sides of `+` need to match. What you can do is define a custom operator to add `Scalar` and `Int`:

```
(+.) :: Scalar -> Int -> Scalar
(Scalar i1) +. i2 = Scalar (i1 + i2)

infixl 6 +.
```

You might also want to use a `newtype` wrapper instead (all you have to do is replace the `data` keyword with `newtype`). This is semantically the same (except in some corner cases with undefined values) but slightly more efficient because newtypes are erased during compilation.