# Haskell addition with custom data type

Tags: haskell

Just need the basic syntax of Haskell explained here, because I'm apparently missing something and I can't find anything explaining how to properly do this.

Given:

```
data Year = Year Integer
```

How do I allow for addition, such as `(Year 2000) + 10` which would return `Year 2010`

I tried

```
instance Num Year where
    (Year a) + (b) = Year (a + b)
```

But that didn't work. Tried a few others, but I thought this was the most obvious solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/27462918/1176156

Comment: Note that years are _points_ (well, intervals) in time, and it only makes sense to shift them by _amounts_ of time. I'd definitely want to model this as an [affine space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.7.2/docs/Data-AffineSpace.html).

Comment: Took a look at this link, and between that and the answer below, I'd say the fromInteger route is closer to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Num` defines `+` like this:

```
(+) :: a -> a -> a
```

So both the left and right sides of `+` have to be the same type. You’re trying to define a `Num` instance where that isn’t the case. If you wanted to, you could make `+` work on two `Year`s:

```
Year a + Year b = Year (a + b)
```

But if you want to be able to add, say, a `Year` and an `Integer`, you’d need to use a different operator name, e.g.:

```
Year a +++ b = Year (a + b)
```

(If you went this route, you might then want to define a precedence for this new operator.)

Comment: `instance Num Year where Year x +++ y = Year (x + y)` is also throwing an error, saying "‘+++’ is not a (visible) method of class ‘Num’".

Comment: @Lucas: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The `+++` definition would be at the top level, not inside the `instance`.